# How to resolve error "object_permission() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am trying to implement an object-level permission. When I run my code, I get an error message saying that I am using too many positional arguments.

```
TypeError: has_object_permission() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

However, when I check the documentation for the Django Rest framework, four arguments are also used.

```
class PostOwnerPermssion(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Check if authenticated user is  story author
    """
    def has_object_permission(self,request,obj,**kwargs):
        if request.user.id == story.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Im happy for any clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: No, those are *named* parameters: `kwargs` are named, so `name=value`, if you call it with `obj.has_object_permission(foo, bar, qux)`, then it will error.

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback?

Comment: Show us the call you're making to `has_object_permission()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, when I check the documentation for the Django Rest framework,
>   four arguments are also used.
>
> ```
> class PostOwnerPermssion(permissions.BasePermission):
>     """
>     Check if authenticated user is  story author
>     """
>     def has_object_permission(self,request,obj,**kwargs):
>         if request.user.id == story.author:
>             return True
>         return False
> ```

**No**, `**kwargs` matches with an arbitrary number of ***named*** parameters, so you can call this with `` my_post_owner_permssion.has_object_permission(request, some_obj, foo=bar, qux=bar2)` `` but *not* with ***positional*** parameters (parameters without a name).

You can implement one (or both) of the following methods:

1. `.has_permission(self, request, view)`; and
2. `.has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)`

What is missing in your case, is the `view` parameter, so you can rewrite this to:

```
class PostOwnerPermssion(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Check if authenticated user is  story author
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.id == obj.author_id
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three positional arguments in `(self,request,obj,**kwargs)`: `self,request,obj`.

You can call it like `obj.has_object_permission(foo, bar)`. Note that `**kwargs` is named argument, so you have to call it with name such as `obj.has_object_permission(foo, bar, named_arg='something')`.